# How to get the oldest document in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index storing logs with a timestamp.

I'm trying to find what is the oldest log.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort by timestamp and limit the search to one result.

```
POST index/_search
{
   "size": 1,
   "sort": { "@timestamp": "asc"},
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   }
}
```